# Polymer - How to go to another view from an <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, routes, polymer

I did my best searching if someone has already asked this, but I couldn't.

I'm trying to link to another view in a  tag (using href), from my html code using Polymer. I'm new with the concepts of this technology, even though it seems pretty easy to use. I tryied with the routing.html, but I don't have clear concepts about the optimal use of this script.

So I was hoping that someone can give me some directions about what to read or what to do in this case.

This was kinda what I was trying to do:

```
<div class="retrieve_link">
    <a href="#" on-click="gototest">Recuperar Contraseña</a>
</div>
```

The javascript section:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

Polymer({
  is: 'avipavo-signin',

  properties: {

  },

  gototest : function(){
      app.route = "managepass";
  }
});
```

})();

And the routing.html:

```
page('/managepass',function(){

    console.log("managepass");

    app.title = 'Nueva Contraseña';
    app.route = 'managepass';
    app.shortView = true;
});
```

Best regards to everyone!

Comment: Look at the Polymer Starter Kit. It uses page.js. https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit

Answer (score 0):

I know 2 popular routing components for Polymer/WebComponents:

[app-router](https://github.com/erikringsmuth/app-router) by Erik Ringsmuth is native web component for routing. Works good with polymer based apps.

Newer and more modular approach is [carbon-route](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/carbon-route) by Polymer team. Read an article about `carbon-route` in polymer blog: https://blog.polymer-project.org/announcements/2016/03/28/carbon-route-released/

Answer (score 0):

To go to your `managepass` route change the `<a>` tag to be following.
`<a href="#!/managepass">Recuperar Contraseña</a>`

The start `#!` is with `hashbang: true`.

The way you navigate your routes with `page.js` is using simple links to the routes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following (in your JS portion)?

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

    Polymer({
      is: 'avipavo-signin',

      properties: {

      },

      gototest : function(){
          page('/managepass');
      }
    })
})();
```

Source: https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/ -- `page(path)`: Navigate to the given path. Using this approach you shouldn't have to worry about using hashbangs or not.